# Is it correct to say "Username and password don't match"?

Tags: meaning

In computing, is it correct to say "Username and password you have entered don't match"? Won't it sound like username and password should be the same?

Comment: Only if you think about it too long. It's really just a shortened form of "The username and password [associated with that username] do not match."

Comment: This might go over better at the UI/UX stack exchange site.  Given that, when a user enter incorrect credentials, a more common paradigm uses words like *incorrect* or *invalid* rather than *do not match*.

Comment: It would be very poor security if they **did** match!

Comment: ("Username or password is invalid" would be a better way to phrase it.)

Comment: There are unstated words there: [The] Username and password you have entered don't match [what we have in the database for the username and password]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usage is correct.

"To match" doesn't always mean "to be identical."  It can mean that a number of things go together, correspond, or form a set.

From [Oxford Dictionaries Online:](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/match)

> VERB: Correspond or cause to correspond in some essential respect; make or be harmonious.
>
> [with object] ‘I thought we'd have primrose walls to match the bath’
>
> [no object] ‘the jacket and trousers do not match’

So just as a jacket can match trousers without the jacket actually being trousers, a password can match a user name if the hash of the entered password is the same as the hash stored for the user name. This doesn't require the password to be character-by-character identical to the user name, or even similar.